# Как сделать этот блок при помощи псевдоэлементов?http://prntscr.com/pu5c45

Tags: html, сss3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать этот блок при помощи псевдоэлементов?

Comment: Да так вроде с делаю но оно не работает